# React-select r.stack.replace is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, react-select

So I'm trying to add a border radius to my react-select, but when I try to add custom styles I got some errors, but I can't seem to find whats going wrong.

```
  function OptionsSelector(props) {
  const customStyles = {
    option: (provided, state) => ({
      ...provided,
      borderBottom: "2px dotted black",
      borderRadius: "8px",
    }),
    control: (provided) => ({
      ...provided,
      marginTop: "5%"
    })
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Select styles={customStyles}></Select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But all I get is the r.stack.replace is not a function. Without the custom style it actually works right, so something in there is messing it up.

New error:

```
    ×  C:\Users\Lucas\Documents\git\front-end-test-2-forked\src\components\OptionsSelector\index.jsx:13:6: C:/Users/Lucas/Documents/git/front-en×  C:\Users\Lucas\Documents\git\front-end-test-2-forked\src\components\OptionsSelector\index.jsx:13:6: C:/Users/Lucas/Documents/git/front-en×  C:\Users\Lucas\Documents\git\front-end-test-2-forked\src\components\OptionsSelector\index.jsx:13:6: C:/Users/Lucas/Documents/git/front-en×  C:\Users\Lucas\Documents\git\front-end-test-2-forked\src\components\OptionsSelector\index.jsx:17:6: C:/Users/Lucas/Documents/git/front-en×  C:\Users\Lucas\Documents\git\front-end-test-2-forked\src\components\OptionsSelector\index.jsx:13:6: C:/Users/Lucas/Documents/git/front-en×  C:\Users\Lucas\Documents\git\front-end-test-2-forked\src\components\OptionsSelector\index.jsx:13:6: C:/Users/Lucas/Documents/git/front-end-test-2-forked/src/components/OptionsSelector/index.jsx: Unexpected token (13:6)
  11 |   const customStyles = {
  12 |     option: (provided) => ({
> 13 |       ...provided,
     |      ^
  14 |       borderBottom: "2px dotted black",
  15 |       borderRadius: "8px",
  16 |     }),
```

Comment: there is nothing wrong with your styling , it should work ! , may be you're using something esle that cause the issue

Comment: When I take the provider out of the return then it stops, but then the styling doesn't work.

Comment: @could you post the provider code ?

Comment: I don't have a provider, I'm using provided in there because I saw in some examples and in the documentation. If I use it then it gives me the error and if I don't then it doesn't work

Comment: reproduced you example it works , [Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-silence-gpl52?file=/src/App.js) , could you try here ,also post the versions you used in your project

Comment: I tried exactly the same example in another enviroment and got a new error.